# Get member object of command sender Discord.js v14

Tags: discord.js

[image]
How do I get the member object of @My Server Nickname (the command sender) given the message id of this message? The message author is the bot.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const channel = await interaction.client.channels.fetch('channelid');
const message = await channel.messages.fetch('messageid');
console.log(message.interaction.user.id); //gives user id of person who sent command
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?